# How can we parse the JSON file such that it gets read by an object automatically?

Tags: python, json

This is my JSON file, though I can access contents as data["bin_contents"]["bin_A"][0] etc, How can I automatically read the input without having to specify "bin_A", "bin_B" etc? Given below is the JSON file:

```
{
  "bin_contents":
  {
    "bin_A":
    [
      "oreo_mega_stuf","champion_copper_plus_spark_plug","expo_dry_erase_board_eraser","kong_duck_dog_toy"
    ],
    "bin_B":
    [
      "genuine_joe_plastic_stir_sticks"
    ],
    "bin_C":
    [
      "munchkin_white_hot_duck_bath_toy"
    ],
    "bin_D":
    [
      "crayola_64_ct"
    ],
    "bin_E":
    [
      "mommys_helper_outlet_plugs","sharpie_accent_tank_style_highlighters","kong_air_dog_squeakair_tennis_ball"
    ],
    "bin_F":
    [
      "stanley_66_052"
    ],
    "bin_G":
    [
      "safety_works_safety_glasses","dr_browns_bottle_brush","laugh_out_loud_joke_book"
    ],
    "bin_H":
    [
      "cheezit_big_original","paper_mate_12_count_mirado_black_warrior"
    ],
    "bin_I":
    [
      "feline_greenies_dental_treats","elmers_washable_no_run_school_glue"
    ],
    "bin_J":
    [
      "mead_index_cards","rolodex_jumbo_pencil_cup","mead_index_cards","first_years_take_and_toss_straw_cup"
    ],
    "bin_K":
    [
      "highland_6539_self_stick_notes","mark_twain_huckleberry_finn"
    ],
    "bin_L":
    [
      "kyjen_squeakin_eggs_plush_puppies","kong_sitting_frog_dog_toy"
    ]
  },

  "work_order":
  [
    {
      "bin": "bin_A",
      "item": "oreo_mega_stuf"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_B",
      "item": "genuine_joe_plastic_stir_sticks"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_C",
      "item": "munchkin_white_hot_duck_bath_toy"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_D",
      "item": "crayola_64_ct"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_E",
      "item": "mommys_helper_outlet_plugs"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_F",
      "item": "stanley_66_052"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_G",
      "item": "safety_works_safety_glasses"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_H",
      "item": "cheezit_big_original"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_I",
      "item": "feline_greenies_dental_treats"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_J",
      "item": "mead_index_cards"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_K",
      "item": "highland_6539_self_stick_notes"
    },
    {
      "bin": "bin_L",
      "item": "kyjen_squeakin_eggs_plush_puppies"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What you want is deserializing json into a object. What I can suggest to you is, research deserializing json in python.

Answer (score 1):

You would iterate over it's key/values

Instead of

```
data["bin_contents"]["bin_A"][0]
```

Use

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print key  # bin_contents
    print value  #  {"bin_A": ["oreo_mega_stuf","champion_copper_plus_spark_plug" ...]}
    for key1, value1 in value.items():
        print key1  # "bin_A
        print value1:  # ["oreo_mega_stuf","champion_copper_plus_spark_plug" ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the data structure vs. hard-coding the keys:

```
for bin, value in data['contents'].items():
    print(bin, value[0])
```